# Web2py Form on-click user Authentication

Tags: python, web2py

I can use decorator to force user to login to submit a form. But I need to set it up the way that when user clicks on on submit then he should be redirected to register/signup.

Currently my form in my controller is like:

```
@auth.requires_login()
def survey_create():
    form = SQLFORM(db.survey).process()
    if form.accepted:
        session.flash = 'Survey Processed'
        redirect(URL('index'))
    return locals()
```

I need to send user registration form once he clicks on submit.

Please advise.

Comment: Do you want to save the form submission and insert in the database only after a successful registration?

Comment: yes exactly. But before that I only want to redirect user to login/signup if he is not signed in. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the controller as follows:

```
def survey_create():
    if auth.is_logged_in():
        def onsuccess(form):
            db.survey.insert(db.survey._filter_fields(form.vars))
            session.flash = 'Survey Processed'
        next_url = URL('default', 'index')
    else:
        def onsuccess(form):
            session.survey_submission = form.vars
            session.flash = 'Please Register'
        next_url = URL('default', 'user', 'register')

    form = SQLFORM(db.survey).process(dbio=False, onsuccess=onsuccess, next=next_url)

    return dict(form=form)
```

When calling `.process`, `dbio` is set to `False` to prevent automatic insertion of the submission into the database. Instead, the `onsuccess` callback and `next_url` URL are used to control what happens upon successful form submission, depending on whether the user is logged in. If the user is not logged in, `form.vars` is stored in the session, and we redirect to the registration page.

In order to insert the saved survey submission *after* successful registration, you can add the following code to a model file (somewhere after `auth` has been defined):

```
def insert_survey(_):
    if 'survey_submission' in session:
        db.survey.insert(db.survey._filter_fields(session.survey_submission))
        del session.survey_submission
        session.flash = 'Survey Processed'
        redirect(URL('default', 'index'))

auth.settings.register_onaccept.append(insert_survey)
```

The above registers a callback that will be called after registration. It checks for a survey submission saved in the session, and if found, it inserts the submission in the database and then removes it from the session.